# Style bootstrap custom-select dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a frontend noob learning bootstrap. I want to create multiple choice list with custom bg and font colors and I am using ["custom-select"](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#select-menu) for it:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <select class="custom-select" style="color: #f50; background-color: #410;">
            <option>option 1</option>
            <option>option 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

It works in chromium, both button and option list have specified colors. However in firefox (59.0.2 on ubuntu) only button changes color, dropdown option list is white. How do I make it work in all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's `custom-select` component isn't a *complete* `<select>` replacement like certain JS solutions (`select2`, `Chosen`, etc).  As such it is still subject to the limitations browsers place on what can and cannot be styled.

Your above example functions exactly as you imply you want in Mozilla Firefox (Desktop) version 59.0.2.  The `<select>` container and the `<option>` values all apply the inline styles you've declared.

In macOS Safari and Google Chrome you'll see a somewhat different result due to how those browsers allow `<select>` to be styled.  You *cannot* style the dropdown portion, so while these browsers will display your desired colors on the `<select>` container, your dropdown will appear in the default stylings.

There are, of course, some exceptions.  Google Chrome allows you to adjust the `font-weight` of your dropdown list.  Certain `-webkit-*`syntaxes can be used for browser-specific adjustments with varied results (and of course, exclusive to browsers using WebKit).

Comment: Is there another way within bootstrap to create styled option list? It seems odd to me that such widely used library lacks such simple thing.

Comment: You could use the `dropdown` component and rely on JavaScript to return the results.  But it is not *Bootstrap* that is lacking here; it is Browser.  As I mentioned, short of a complete JavaScript replacement you're always going to be limited in what can be achieved.  Bootstrap's `custom-select` tries to offer you the closest design to their own aesthetic without trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: If using dropdown I'd need: a) to change its label on each selection from js, b) to calculate its min width as max across text widths of all options and then set it from js, c) set default (initial) option from js. This seems like too much, esp. b. For now I'll just try to use libraries you mentioned.